# where is the default system variable value is configured in mariadb?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, parameters, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I am looking to find where the system variable "binlog_format" is configured in mariadb on EC2(10.3.29-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04). However running "show variables" display the binlog format.

this value should be configured somewhere and i cannot seem to find it anywhere?

I have checked in the following places

```
mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1
```

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:

```
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
& /etc/initi.d/*
```

If this is not explicitly configured(since default value is MIXED in mariadb), can i safely assume i can overwrite this value under [mysqld]?

OR run "`SET GLOBAL binlog_format=ROW`" ?

please advise

Comment: That SET won't persist.  Put the setting in the config file.  Or create the file if it is missing.

Comment: `my_print_defaults --mysqld` is a good way to see config options of the server though running as user mysql to be sure the same file are read. Yes assumptions are right. Note `show variables` can show session variable that may have different values than `show global variables`.

Comment: @danblack provided command seems to return some variables and its value, but its not showing the variable "binlog_format" which i am looking for

Comment: @RickJames, can you please clarify, when you mentioned "it wont persist" - meaning until the restart happens ?

Comment: True.  It will  not persist past the next restart of mysqld.  Here are some other places that might have my.cnf:      /etc/my.cnf
    /etc/mysql/my.cnf
    $MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf
    [datadir]/my.cnf
    ~/.my.cnf
plus any subdirectories of those.

Comment: And `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format';` shows the specific item (to avoid the giant list).  Change `GLOBAL` to `SESSION` to see if you have a difference for your connection.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for the response. both global and session show variables returns "MIXED" in my case. I checked in all the folders mentioned and still no luck. I need to run AWS DMS to migrate from mariadb to aurora mysql, which require binlog format to be ROW. Since this is one time work, i am thinking to use the SET variable to change the binlog format for DMS to work and drop this mariadb db once migration is completed, if i still could not find the correct *.cnf file.